# How to convert slim to html?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, slim-lang

I am new to ruby gems and I have tried to find information about how to compile slim to html. There is a `slimrb` command, but it did not work. How do I convert a slim file to a html file?

Comment: you should provide more information, how did you run `slimrb` ? In what way did it not work?

Comment: I used the `slimbr -c` command inside the directory of the file I want to compile. I expected that in that same directed a file called `index.html` would be created, but it did not happen. What happened, is that the slim code I typed into the command line would be converted afterwards within the command line. I want to transform `index.slim` into `index.html`. I consider my question as being pretty straightforward, though.

Answer (score 4):

I assume local variables are missing. In that case, give them with `-l` option. For example,

```
$ cat template.slim
div
  p= message
$ slimrb template.slim -l '{"message": "hello"}'
<div><p>hello</p></div>
```

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

Shouichi's answer is what you're looking for.

However from your comment, I understand you also want to redirect the output to a file (the .html file). The way this can be done depends on the shell you're using. For example in (ba)sh you could do it like this:

```
slimrb template.slim -l '{"message": "hello"}' > template.html
```